# How to display an interstitial ad from Admob with AndEngine?

Tags: android, multithreading, admob, andengine

I am using andengine and I am switching between two scenes. My intention is to put an interstitial ad between the transition. This is my code so far:

```
public void showGameOver(){
 mainactivity=new MainActivity();

  mainactivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            interstitial = new InterstitialAd(mainactivity);
            interstitial.setAdUnitId("MY AD UNIT ID");

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                interstitial.show();
              }


        }

    });

 interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAdLoaded() {

         }

         @Override
         public void onAdClosed() {
             // Proceed to the next level.
            setCurrentScene(gameover);
  res.engine.setScene(gameover);


  gameover.loadResources();
  gameover.create();
         }
     });
```

}

The above code( without the interstitial ad code) switches to my gameover scene. When I put the interstitial ad code, my app crashes. The interstitial ad is supposed to show the ad, and when it closes, my gameover scene should show. I put in the correct ad unit id.

Logcat says: cannot create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare().

I searched this up and solutions state that I must put it on the runonuithread method, which I did.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate a new activity via `mainactivity=new MainActivity();` and use that. Instead you should pass the game's underlying activity to your gameOver() method and use that:

```
public void showGameOver(Activity yourActivity){

  yourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(mainactivity);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("MY AD UNIT ID");

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
          }


    }

});
```